# How to pass a number as TEXT through a Power BI Parameter?

Tags: powerbi

Should be a pretty simple ask. I have a Text parameter used for querying on a specific model of machine. Usually the model looks something like this : "330F".  Every once in a while though a model is simply a number, "330" for example.  What do I have to do to be able to pass 330 as a Text parameter. I have tried quotes but that doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I had my parameter type set as ANY thinking that would allow for both Text and Numbers.  However, when I go to Manage Parameters and change the Type to TEXT it solves the problem.